# Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while updating geomesa indices

Tags: indexing, geomesa

I have some tables in geomesa, such as MyFeature. I have to verify if it is possible to modify the indices.

I'm trying the following instruction from CLI:

```
geomesa-accumulo add-attribute-index -u username -p pwd-f MyFeature -c project.mycatalog -a myAttr --coverage full
```

When I run the above command from CLI, in my geomesa_accumulo home directory, I get the following exception

> (blah bla blah my feature schema blah blah blah)
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils
>           at org.parboiled.MatcherContext.runMatcher(MatcherContext.java:366)
>           at org.parboiled.matchers.SequenceMatcher.match(SequenceMatcher.java:46)
>           at org.parboiled.parserunners.BasicParseRunner.match(BasicParseRunner.java:77)
>           at org.parboiled.MatcherContext.runMatcher(MatcherContext.java:351)
>           at org.parboiled.matchers.FirstOfMatcher.match(FirstOfMatcher.java:41)
>           at org.parboiled.parserunners.BasicParseRunner.match(BasicParseRunner.java:77)
>           at org.parboiled.MatcherContext.runMatcher(MatcherContext.java:351)
>           at org.parboiled.matchers.SequenceMatcher.match(SequenceMatcher.java:46)
>           at org.parboiled.parserunners.BasicParseRunner.match(BasicParseRunner.java:77)
>           at org.parboiled.MatcherContext.runMatcher(MatcherContext.java:351)
>           at org.parboiled.matchers.SequenceMatcher.match(SequenceMatcher.java:46)
>           at org.parboiled.parserunners.BasicParseRunner.match(BasicParseRunner.java:77)
>           at org.parboiled.MatcherContext.runMatcher(MatcherContext.java:351)
>           at org.parboiled.matchers.FirstOfMatcher.match(FirstOfMatcher.java:41)
>           at org.parboiled.parserunners.BasicParseRunner.match(BasicParseRunner.java:77)
>           at org.parboiled.MatcherContext.runMatcher(MatcherContext.java:351)
>           at org.parboiled.matchers.SequenceMatcher.match(SequenceMatcher.java:46)
>           at org.parboiled.parserunners.BasicParseRunner.match(BasicParseRunner.java:77)
>           at org.parboiled.MatcherContext.runMatcher(MatcherContext.java:351)
>           at org.parboiled.matchers.FirstOfMatcher.match(FirstOfMatcher.java:41)
>           at org.parboiled.parserunners.BasicParseRunner.match(BasicParseRunner.java:77)
>           at org.parboiled.MatcherContext.runMatcher(MatcherContext.java:351)
>           at org.parboiled.matchers.SequenceMatcher.match(SequenceMatcher.java:46)
>           at org.parboiled.parserunners.BasicParseRunner.match(BasicParseRunner.java:77)
>           at org.parboiled.MatcherContext.runMatcher(MatcherContext.java:351)
>           at org.parboiled.matchers.SequenceMatcher.match(SequenceMatcher.java:46)
>           at org.parboiled.parserunners.BasicParseRunner.match(BasicParseRunner.java:77)
>           at org.parboiled.MatcherContext.runMatcher(MatcherContext.java:351)
>           at org.parboiled.parserunners.BasicParseRunner.run(BasicParseRunner.java:72)
>           at org.parboiled.parserunners.ReportingParseRunner.runBasicMatch(ReportingParseRunner.java:86)
>           at org.parboiled.parserunners.ReportingParseRunner.run(ReportingParseRunner.java:66)
>           at org.parboiled.scala.parserunners.ReportingParseRunner.run(ReportingParseRunner.scala:34)
>           at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.geotools.SimpleFeatureSpecParser$.parse(SimpleFeatureSpecParser.scala:38)
>           at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.geotools.SimpleFeatureSpecParser$.parse(SimpleFeatureSpecParser.scala:28)
>           at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.geotools.SimpleFeatureTypes$.createType(SimpleFeatureTypes.scala:110)
>           at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.geotools.MetadataBackedDataStore$$anonfun$getSchema$1.apply(MetadataBackedDataStore.scala:185)
>           at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.geotools.MetadataBackedDataStore$$anonfun$getSchema$1.apply(MetadataBackedDataStore.scala:185)
>           at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
>           at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.geotools.MetadataBackedDataStore.getSchema(MetadataBackedDataStore.scala:185)
>           at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.geotools.GeoMesaDataStore.getSchema(GeoMesaDataStore.scala:174)
>           at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloDataStore.getSchema(AccumuloDataStore.scala:228)
>           at org.locationtech.geomesa.jobs.mapreduce.GeoMesaAccumuloInputFormat.init(GeoMesaAccumuloInputFormat.scala:241)
>           at org.locationtech.geomesa.jobs.mapreduce.GeoMesaAccumuloInputFormat.createRecordReader(GeoMesaAccumuloInputFormat.scala:307)
>           at org.locationtech.geomesa.jobs.mapreduce.GeoMesaAccumuloInputFormat.createRecordReader(GeoMesaAccumuloInputFormat.scala:164)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.(MapTask.java:521)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:177)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:171) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils
>           at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.text.BasicParser$$anonfun$singleQuotedString$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(BasicParser.scala:49)
>           at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.text.BasicParser$$anonfun$singleQuotedString$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(BasicParser.scala:49)
>           at org.parboiled.scala.rules.Rule$$anonfun$exec$1.apply(Rule.scala:197)
>           at org.parboiled.scala.rules.Rule$$anonfun$exec$1.apply(Rule.scala:193)
>           at org.parboiled.scala.rules.Rule$$anonfun$push$1.apply(Rule.scala:133)
>           at org.parboiled.scala.rules.Rule$$anonfun$push$1.apply(Rule.scala:132)
>           at org.parboiled.scala.rules.Rule$$anon$1.run(Rule.scala:129)
>           at org.parboiled.matchers.ActionMatcher.match(ActionMatcher.java:96)
>           at org.parboiled.parserunners.BasicParseRunner.match(BasicParseRunner.java:77)
>           at org.parboiled.MatcherContext.runMatcher(MatcherContext.java:351)
>           ... 51 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 61 more

However, in $geomesa_accumulo_home/lib/ I see the following jar (that shoud contain apache common text):

commons-text-1.4.jar

UPDATE:

If I try with yarn with the following command:

```
yarn jar /opt/geomesa-accumulo_2.11-2.2.1/lib/geomesa-accumulo-jobs_2.11-2.2.1.jar org.locationtech.geomesa.jobs.index.AttributeIndexJob --geomesa.input.user user --geomesa.input.password pwd --geomesa.input.tableName catalog --geomesa.input.feature FeatureName --geomesa.index.coverage full --geomesa.index.attributes AttributeName
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.locationtech.geomesa.jobs.index.AttributeIndexJob
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:158)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from your distributed yarn classpath. commons-text-1.4 should be added to the libjars argument and distributed with the map reduce job. However, there may be a conflicting version already present on your yarn classpath, so you should check for that. The libjars argument is created using `geomesa-accumulo-tools.jar!org/locationtech/geomesa/accumulo/tools/ingest-libjars.list`, so verify that hasn't been modified as well.

Comment: Shall you give an eye to my edit, please? I tried with YARN as well